# BLE on Android - E/bt_btif: bta_gattc_process_indicate, ignore HID ind/notificiation

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Our app is used to download large amounts of data from Bluetooth Low Energy device via characteristic change notifications.

During the download process on at least one android device we are getting such errors on logcat (it gets repeated many times during the download):

```
E/bt_btif: bta_gattc_process_indicate, ignore HID ind/notificiation
```

**What does the error mean and how can I fix it?**

Comment: What Android version do you have? Is the peripheral a HID device?

Comment: @emil Android 7.0 (Sony xperia XZ). I'm not sure if the peripheral counts as HID device - it is a health device that repeatedly takes measurements about human body and user can later download the measurements with BLE - i.e. it does not send data over time (as one would expect from a BLE device) but instead sends all the accumulated data at once, upon request from the user.

Comment: I only get this error with Sony Xperia too, other devices OK.

Comment: I got similar error on an Android Asus Zen Phone Z017D also called Asus ZenPhone 3

Comment: Was anyone able to stop getting this message?  It's flooding my logcat logs.